# I can't connect to MariaDB with Java (Driver not found)

Tags: java, mariadb

I tried to connect to a MariaDB but it doesn't work

Here is my Code:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mariadb://192.168.1.45:3306";
    String username = "...";
    String password = "...";


    System.out.println("Connecting database...");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed " + e);
    }
```

I always get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://192.168.1.45:3306
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Add a driver for mariadb.

Comment: did you add the driver for mariadb in your classpath? how are you building and running your project? manually? maven? gradle? something else? please, provide a [miniml reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look to the documentation for MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#getting-a-new-connection

It says:

> **Getting a New Connection**
>
> There are two standard ways to get a connection:
>
> **Using DriverManager**
>
> The preferred way to get a connection with MariaDB Connector/J is to use the DriverManager class. When the DriverManager class is used to locate and load MariaDB Connector/J, the application needs no further configuration. The DriverManager class will automatically load MariaDB Connector/J and allow it to be used in the same way as any other JDBC driver.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/DB?user=root&password=myPassword");
> ```
>
> The legacy way of loading a JDBC driver also still works for MariaDB  Connector/J. e.g.: `Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")`
>
> jdbc:mysql scheme compatibility MariaDB Connector/J 3.0 only accepts
> jdbc:mariadb: as the protocol in connection strings by default. When
> both MariaDB Connector/J and the MySQL drivers are found in the
> class-path, using jdbc:mariadb: as the protocol helps to ensure that
> Java chooses MariaDB Connector/J.

But this implies that you have installed the proper Jar file on your `CLASSPATH`; see [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#installing-mariadb-connectorj) for the details.

From your code and the reported error message, you do not have the MariaDB JDBC driver on your `CLASSPATH`, but that for MySQL.